# Model Constraint - User Can Only Vote Once Per Post

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, cancan

I want to restrict users to voting up or down on posts and each User can only cast one vote for each Post. I have to check if the User voted on the post before I create a new relation.

I am already using CanCan for other restrictions like "the User can only edit its own Post", but this case is something different, so I want the best practice. After adding an uniqueness-validation to the model should I implement the rule above ("one vote per post and user") via CanCan or just in the controller?

Answer (score 1):

To me it sounds like neither, this is a validation that should be performed in the model layer IMO.

Comment: I already have a validation in my model. But I dont want to show the link to vote something if the user can't - so I have to check for the ability one more time. The question is, should I put a rule into cancan (so I can just use can? in the view) or should I add the direct condition in controller and view?

Answer (score 1):

To me, this is not a CanCan job. On a cursory review of the issue, my sense is that I would create a predicate method in the model and call that from my view.

```
def votable?
  if blahblahblag
    true
  else
    false
  end
end
```

In the (haml) view:

```
- if model_name.votable?
  = cool_markup_tag
```

Something like that ... just a rough sketch but, to me, this keeps the controller clean and the check in the model where I think it belongs (and is along Logan's comment/answer).